# Magento 2: Product collection filter with custom attributes with like

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, collection, product-collection

I am using magento 2.3.3 i have custom module in that i am using search when any one search i am filter products **name** like it is working fine but now i want add extra attributes.I have created product attribute **product_title** as text field not required.

I have created 2 products

**one  name=>test.**

second one is **name=>text ,product_title=>7986**

when customer search test key work no results found.

```
$collection = $this->_productCollection
                     ->create()
                     ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                     ->addFieldToFilter('name', ['like' => '%'.$queryString.'%']);
```

if i use above code with name filter it showing result

```
$collection = $this->_productCollection
                                    ->create()
                                    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                                    //->addFieldToFilter('name', ['like' => '%'.$queryString.'%'])
                                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
                                    array(
                                            array('attribute' => 'name', 'like', '%' . $queryString . '%'),
                                            array('attribute' => 'oem_no','like', '%' . $queryString . '%')
                                        ),
                                     );
```

if i use both filter no result 0 records.

My requirement i need to search search key word with both attributes if match keyword name or product_title need get that result

```
 SELECT `e`.*,`v`.`entity_id`,`v`.`attribute_id`,`v`.`value` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` as `v` on `v`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id` WHERE `v`.`attribute_id` IN (70,195) AND `value` LIKE '%test%'
```

this raw query getting result in phpmyadmin same like this need result

this is my complete file

```
    <?php
/**
 * Webkul Software.
 *
 * @category  Webkul
 * @package   Webkul_MpAssignProduct
 * @author    Webkul
 * @copyright Copyright (c) Webkul Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
namespace Webkul\MpAssignProduct\Block\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory as ProductCollection;
use Webkul\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;
use Webkul\MpAssignProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Items\CollectionFactory as AssignProductCollection;

class ProductList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Webkul\MpAssignProduct\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $_assignHelper;

    /**
     * @var ProductCollection
     */
    protected $_productCollection;
    
    /**
     * @var AssignProductCollection
     */
    protected $_assignProductCollection;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_mpProductCollection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $_productStatus;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_productVisibility;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    protected $_productList;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Webkul\MpAssignProduct\Helper\Data $helper
     * @param ProductCollection $productCollectionFactory
     * @param CollectionFactory $mpProductCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Webkul\MpAssignProduct\Helper\Data $helper,
        ProductCollection $productCollectionFactory,
        CollectionFactory $mpProductCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        AssignProductCollection $assignProductCollection,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute $eavAttribute,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $context->getStoreManager();
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_assignHelper = $helper;
        $this->_productCollection = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_mpProductCollection = $mpProductCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->_productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        $this->_assignProductCollection = $assignProductCollection;
        $this->_eavAttribute = $eavAttribute;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Product List'));
    }

    /**
     * @return bool|\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     */
    public function getAllProducts()
    {
        if (!$this->_productList) {
            $queryString = $this->_assignHelper->getQueryString();
            $page=($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
            $pageSize=($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 1;

            if ($queryString != '') {
                $customerId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerId();
                $sellercollection = $this->_mpProductCollection
                                        ->create()
                                        ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id', ['eq' => $customerId])
                                        ->addFieldToSelect('mageproduct_id');
                $products = [];
                foreach ($sellercollection as $data) {
                    array_push($products, $data->getMageproductId());
                }
                $sellerAssigncollection = $this->_assignProductCollection
                                ->create()
                                ->addFieldToFilter('seller_id', $customerId)
                                ->addFieldToSelect('product_id');
                foreach ($sellerAssigncollection as $data) {
                    array_push($products, $data->getProductId());
                }

                $allowedTypes = $this->_assignHelper->getAllowedProductTypes();
                $collection = $this->_productCollection
                                    ->create()
                                    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                                    //->addFieldToFilter('name', ['like' => '%'.$queryString.'%']);
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('name', ['like' => '%'.$queryString.'%'])->addFieldToFilter('oem_no', ['like' => '%'.$queryString.'%']);
//                                    ->addAttributeToFilter(
//                                    array(
//                                            //array('attribute' => 'name', 'like', '%' . $queryString . '%'),
//                                            array('attribute' => 'oem_no','like', '%' . $queryString . '%')
//                                        ),
//                                        '',
//                                        'left'
//                                    );
                echo $collection->getSelect();
                                echo count($collection);
//                                foreach ($collection as $collections){
//                                    print_r("sdkjfhdskjhf".$collections->getData());
//                                }
                $attributeId = $this->_eavAttribute->getIdByCode('catalog_product', 'oem_no');
                print_r($attributeId);
                die("here");
                //$collection->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left');
                $collection->addFieldToFilter('type_id', ['in' => $allowedTypes]);
                if (count($products) > 0) {
                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['nin' => $products]);
                }
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->_productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()]);
                $collection->setVisibility($this->_productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds());
                $collection->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
            } else {
                $collection = $this->_productCollection
                                    ->create()
                                    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                                    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', 0);
            }
            $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
            $collection->setCurPage($page);
            $this->_productList = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productList;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        if ($this->getAllProducts()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager::class,
                'mpassignproduct.product.list.pager'
            )
            ->setShowPerPage(true)
            ->setCollection(
                $this->getAllProducts()
            );
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getAllProducts()->load();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    /**
     * Get Current Currency Symbol
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrencySymbol()
    {
        $symbol = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();
        return $symbol;
    }
}
```

can any one give solution how to get result

Answer (score 0):

If you just need  an and operation you can call addFieldToFilter twice to get the result as follows;

```
$collection = $this->_productCollection
                 ->create()
                 ->addFieldToSelect('*')
                 ->addFieldToFilter('name', ['like' => '%'.$queryString.'%'])->addFieldToFilter('product_title', ['like' => '%'.$queryString.'%']);
```

Comment: i alredy tried but no getting result count is 0.search key word need to check name and product title if match any field get result

Comment: i think given answer is like and conditions i need or keyword exist name or title we need to get data